# Static files won't work if debug = False

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy django project to heroku. When I have debug as False my static files won't work. If I deploy debug = True in my settings page, the static files work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production (that is, `DEBUG = False`), you need to use the [`dj-static` library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static) as detailed in the official [documentation on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)